# How to make html builtin <video> changing time smoothly

Tags: javascript, html

I use code

```
<video src="./t.mp4" controls width="400" height="200"/>
```

[image]

when drag controls slider change video time, it has delay to apply new time video frame, I see [plyr official demo](https://plyr.io/), drag controls can smoothly change video time, how does it impl?

[image]

I guess it's video source issue, but I don't know how to make video change time smoothly

Answer (score -1):

I can only refer to the posted example from plyr.
When scrolling through the video, only a low resolution image is shown, which will transform to the full quality for playing.

This may be either realized using a low quality viode file, which is preloaded, or by using precreated screenshots (e.g. 1 per second), which may also bee used for the hovering. (See the network tab of the developer tools in your browser!).

In the example of plyr, I expect that the screenshots are used, as I could not see a request for a second video file.